# Texture appearing blurry

Tags: unity, tiles, tiled

I've just created another scene in Tiled and imported it into Unity using Tiled2Unity and I'm having a strange issue, while the image looks crisp and as it should in Tiled, when imported into Unity it's appearing blurry (all of the graphics in the prefab Tiled2Unity creates).

My tiles are 64x64 and the scale is PPU is set to 1.

Tiled (how I want it to look) -

[image]

Unity (how it imports)

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you set the filter mode of the image to "Point (no filter)" ? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

Comment: When importing the prefab I don't have the option for the filter mode: http://imgur.com/sNo5WKv

Comment: Not the _prefab_. The _texture_. That setting is on the texture.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer - Found it, sorry about that, was looking in completely the wrong place. Thanks your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the texture you have imported in the `Project` tab, and then in the `Inspector`, set `Filter Mode` to `Point`.

[image]

Comment: Pointed at with a big red arrow. Just how I like it.

Comment: :) Done using the wonderful [Skitch](https://evernote.com/skitch/).

Answer (score 0):

I needed the change the filter mode, and compression mode against the texture that Tiled2Unity imported, this was found under "Assets/Tiled2Unity/Textures", altering the settings in the inspector against the texture made the blur go away.

Comment: I think this answer needs more big red arrows. A picture and a few arrows pointing at the stuff you changed would be great.